# Get list of available devices on bluetooth Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mobile, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I want to know how can i list all available devices
by name for connection with them.
I tried to find on MS site but there was no explanation for listing all devices.
My code:

```
   PeerFinder.Start();
                PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth"] = "";
                var peers = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();

                if (peers.Count == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Peer not found.");
                }
```

Comment: There is a nice tutorial on MSDN pages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207007(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_BluetoothAPI

Comment: i tried that not working ... I get peer not find i even tried to pair to device before that it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it is not possible to list all bluetooth devices it's only possible to view all paired devices. So i paired the device and then open a connection to it to see if the device bluetooth is on. If i can't connect to it it's off.